# How to fix script.sh: line 1: Builing...: not found problem?

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I have used both jenkins/jenkins:latest and jenkinsci/blueocean:latest docker images with pipeline script from SCM settings.

General setting "GitHub project" was enabled with https://github.com/alamsarker/test

Now When I build. its shows the following error:

```
+ Builing...
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/pipeline-test@tmp/durable-2aac8cac/script.sh: line 1: Builing...: not found
```

Can you please to fix the issue?

I run docker by:

```
docker run \
  -u root \
  --rm \
  -d \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -p 50000:50000 \
  -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  jenkinsci/blueocean
```

My Jenkinsfile is simple as follows:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'Builing...'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'Testing...'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                sh 'Deploying...'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The commands expected in `sh` are not valid Linux or application commands. Are you trying to just `echo` statements here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the pipeline step `sh` is used to execute linux cmd.  `Building` is not a valid linux cmd, that's why you get the error.

If you want to print out some word you can use step `echo` which is cross-platform or execute the linux cmd: `echo` via step `sh`, like `sh 'echo Building...'` which only work on linux-like agent.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Builing...'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo Testing...'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying...'
            }
        }
    }
}
```